# How do you setup SASS and Compass in Foundation 6

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass, zurb-foundation-6

I created a project called A by calling Foundation New A in a Windows command prompt. After CD A and running Compass Watch changes from _settings.scss are not caught by Compass. I CD to SCSS and run Compass again but same result. My question is how can I make Compass catch changes in _settings,scss and app.scss? Also where is _settings.scss imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation Watch is Libass...import _settings.scsss in app.scss